# Mathematics behind line of code for projection in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, projection

I found a possible projection for a point onto a plane. While debugging I wanted to understand the mathematics behind it a bit more.
The Code is:

```
[x2d;y2d] = null([a,b,c]).'*[x3d;y3d;z3d];
```

where `[a,b,c]` is the normal vector of a plane and `[x3d, y3d,z3d]` is the 3-dimensional point to project onto the plane.

What I already found about how the code works is that it first calculates the null space (in Matlab there are two different `null` functions: one "calculates an orthonormal basis for the null space", the other "returns a list of vectors that form the basis for the null space". Since both have the same syntax, I am not sure which one is called). The output of `null` is then transposed and multiplied with the 3-dimensional vector.

What I wanted to ask is

- Do I understand it correctly?
- Why it often says that this calculation has multiple possible results?
  The output of Matlab is one single result even if I calculate the different steps of this line of code step by step.

The thought behind this post is that I am not so sure that I took the right plane to project upon.

Thank you everyone for an answer!

Comment: In this case you can rotate the basis by an arbitrary angle around the surface normal without changing the final result. So the `null()` is not unique.

Comment: What does “there are two different `null` functions” mean? Of course MATLAB itself has only [one](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html). Did you add a function yourself? Did you look at a method of a class? If you type `which null` it will tell you which `null` is called. If you type `help null` it will show you the help for that same one.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers!  It starts to make more sense.  I forgot about the "which null" command, and I will try this.  The two null()-functions from Matlab are found linked here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html and https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/null.html , which both have the same syntax. There has to be a difference, so that Matlab knows which function to call, but at least I don't see it.